# Make for loop continue until a goal is accomplished

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, arduino

I need to be able to find 5 sequential bits of EEPROM memory, ideally closest to 2 (as I have bit #1 & 2 associated with other data and want things to be kept organized). I developed this code which works, but the for loop continues after it has found a good set of numbers.

```cpp
Serial.println("got to assignment number finder");
for (int AssignCheck = 2; AssignCheck < 250; AssignCheck++){
  Serial.println("Finding a good assignment number " + String(AssignCheck));
  if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck) == 255){          //Looks for a blank space which can be used to store the new card
    if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 1) == 255){
      if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 2) == 255){
        if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 3) == 255){
          if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 4) == 255){
            Serial.println("Found assignment numbers " + String(AssignCheck) + " through to " + String(int(AssignCheck) + 4) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
            int StoreValue = AssignCheck;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then thought I could put a while loop around it, and have the while loop stop once a variable is set to 0 as opposed to 1, so I wrote this: (notice the introduction of the while loop, the variable and the `Scanner = 0` line in the middle).

```cpp
Serial.println("got to assignment number finder");
int Scanner = 1;
while (Scanner == 1){
  for (int AssignCheck = 2; AssignCheck < 250; AssignCheck++){
    Serial.println("Finding a good assignment number " + String(AssignCheck) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
    if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck) == 255){          //Looks for a blank space which can be used to store the new card
      if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 1) == 255){
        if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 2) == 255){
          if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 3) == 255){
            if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 4) == 255){
              Scanner = 0;
              Serial.println("Found assignment numbers " + String(AssignCheck) + " through to " + String(int(AssignCheck) + 4) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
              int StoreValue = AssignCheck;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It correctly identifies and sets the variable to 0 when I want, but the while loop doesn't seem to have an impact and the loop continues to produce sets of numbers which could work.

As a novice coder myself, I'm not sure what I could try next.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just add a `break;` in the last `if`?

Comment: Or add a check for the second break condition into the condition in the `for` loop, if you need the while for something else

Comment: How to not write proper C code: use 5 nested if statements instead of a loop. Also, why is 5 non-programmed eeprom cells the desired result? This doesn't make any sense. XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these case you can use the instruction `break`:

```cpp
Serial.println("got to assignment number finder");
for (int AssignCheck = 2; AssignCheck < 250; AssignCheck++){
  Serial.println("Finding a good assignment number " + String(AssignCheck));
  if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck) == 255){          //Looks for a blank space which can be used to store the new card
    if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 1) == 255){
      if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 2) == 255){
        if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 3) == 255){
          if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 4) == 255){
            Serial.println("Found assignment numbers " + String(AssignCheck) + " through to " + String(int(AssignCheck) + 4) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
            int StoreValue = AssignCheck;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx), it does exactly what you want.

***Please note that your second attempt doesn't work because the `for loop` is inside the while: it completes before the whole `for loop` and, after, it compare the "scanner" variable of the `while loop`***

You can correct it in this way:

```cpp
Serial.println("got to assignment number finder");
int Scanner = 1;
for (int AssignCheck = 2; (AssignCheck < 250) && (Scanner == 1); AssignCheck++){
  Serial.println("Finding a good assignment number " + String(AssignCheck) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
  if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck) == 255){          //Looks for a blank space which can be used to store the new card
    if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 1) == 255){
      if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 2) == 255){
        if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 3) == 255){
          if (EEPROM.read(AssignCheck + 4) == 255){
            Scanner = 0;
            Serial.println("Found assignment numbers " + String(AssignCheck) + " through to " + String(int(AssignCheck) + 4) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
            int StoreValue = AssignCheck;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Reading EEPROM is expensive, please consider this:

```cpp
Serial.println("got to assignment number finder");
int Scanner = 1;
char rollingBuffer[5];
rollingBuffer[0] = EEPROM.read(2 + 0);
rollingBuffer[1] = EEPROM.read(2 + 1);
rollingBuffer[2] = EEPROM.read(2 + 2);
rollingBuffer[3] = EEPROM.read(2 + 3);
rollingBuffer[4] = EEPROM.read(2 + 4);
pointRoll = 0;
for (int AssignCheck = 7; (AssignCheck < 255); AssignCheck++)
{
    if ((rollingBuffer[0] == 255) && (rollingBuffer[1] == 255) && (rollingBuffer[2] == 255) && (rollingBuffer[3] == 255) && (rollingBuffer[4] == 255))
    {
        Serial.println("Found assignment numbers " + String(AssignCheck-5) + " through to " + String(int(AssignCheck-1)) + ".  Scanner value = " + String(Scanner));
        int StoreValue = AssignCheck;
        break;
    }
    rollingBuffer[pointRoll] = EEPROM.read(AssignCheck);
    pointRoll++;
    if (pointRoll > 4) pointRoll = 0;
}
```

Comment: "Reading EEPROM is expensive" So why read it 5 times if that's not necessary for the algorithm?